# Crop and Upload image using jQuery/Java

Tags: java, jquery, html, servlets, crop

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that allows the following:

1. Select/Browse an image (from user's file system)
2. Preview the image, with ability to CROP
3. Upload the cropped image to server (JAVA Servlet)

Any pointers for this?

P.S. : I have found numerous standalone image cropping plugins (that work on pre-defined images), but not ones that allow uploading a custom image as well (over Java servlets).

Answer (score 1):

One way, to crop image before actually upload it to the server in HTML5 supported browsers, is explained [here](http://www.pandamatak.com/people/anand/blog/2010/11/clientside_image_crop_and_then.html). Mentioned solution is combination of: JCrop, JQuery, HTML5's File and Canvas APIs.

The other way to go (for non HTML5 browsers) is:

1. Select/browse image
2. Upload it to server (as temporary image)
3. Preview the image, with ability to CROP
4. Send CROP coordinates to server
5. Crop and save image on the server side

Comment: I used JCrop/JQuery with ASP.NET for some crop/preview/upload functionality a while ago. It was a surprisingly pleasent experience!

Answer (score 0):

In short you would need to do following.

Use HTML "multipart" form to post image to servlet

```
<form name="frm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/saveimage" method="POST">
  <input type="file" name="filetoupload" />    
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

In servlet write this file to a "public" folder so that it is accessible to browser. You can use http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/ for this purpose in case you are using Servlets. In case you are using web app framework, the framework may offer you a way to upload binary data.

Return page with link/reference to the uploaded image. You may want to use some sort of random file name generation algorithm to avoid file reference collision.

```
<img src="/public/random-image.jpg"/>
```

Use JCrop http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html to get crop coordinates. JCrop documentation is very verbose about how to use it. Note that you would need to initialize JCrop to bind with the image reference above.

Write another servlet to which you can POST/GET the cropped coordinates and do whatever you want to with it.